# Spatial Indexing in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I know R-tree spatial indexing from H2 using in Apache Ignite. I want to know how this index is created among the nodes of a cluster. Is it global? I mean does it create one single R-tree over all the data among the nodes of a cluster? Or it creates separate R-tree for each node of a cluster? If the R-tree's are separate for each node, then how it performs spatial-join among the nodes. My final question, what's the purpose of B+-tree here. I saw in the document; a B+ tree manages indexes and data. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it global? I mean does it create one single R-tree over all the data among the nodes of a cluster? Or it creates separate R-tree for each node of a cluster?

Separate trees, one per node.

> If the R-tree's are separate for each node, then how it performs spatial-join among the nodes.

Same rules as for non-spatial queries, I believe. If you collocate the data so that the rows that should be joined are stored on the same node then you just do local joins. If you don't collocate the data, you have to use `setDistributedJoins(true)` - it will cause Ignite to send all rows that pass single-table `WHERE` filters to the querying node, then perform the join there. See [this page](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/distributed-joins) for details on collocated vs distributed joins.

> My final question, what's the purpose of B+-tree here.

Primary index and regular secondary indexes in Ignite are B+-trees. Spatial secondary indexes are R-trees.